# Log files are not created when executing single file application

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I'm trying to create a single file executable for my console application. The problem is that logging files are not created for some reason. If I run application in Visual studios, simple debug mode then everything works fine, I can see log file appear in the \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 folder.

This is what publishing settings I use

[image]

I am using NLog for logging, and that's how my code looks regarding that

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    builder.AddNLog("nlog.config");
});
LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));
```

and thats appsettings.json where I hold my nlog configurations

```
{
    "NLog": {
        "targets": {
            "console": {
                "type": "ColoredConsole",
                "layout": "${longdate}| ${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message}   ${exception:format=tostring}",
                "rowHighlightingRules": [
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Trace",
                        "foregroundColor": "DarkGray"
                    },
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Debug",
                        "foregroundColor": "DarkGray"
                    },
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Info",
                        "foregroundColor": "White"
                    },
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Warn",
                        "foregroundColor": "Yellow"
                    },
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Error",
                        "foregroundColor": "Red"
                    },
                    {
                        "condition": "level == LogLevel.Fatal",
                        "foregroundColor": "Red"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "allLogFile": {
                "type": "file",
                "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/allLog.txt",
                "archiveFileName": "${basedir}/logs/allLog.{#}.txt",
                "archiveNumbering": "Date",
                "archiveEvery": "Day",
                "archiveDateFormat": "yyyyMMdd",
                "layout": "${longdate}| ${uppercase:${level}}|  ${logger}|  ${message}   ${exception:format=tostring}"
            },
            "importantLogFile": {
                "type": "file",
                "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/importantLog.txt",
                "archiveFileName": "${basedir}/logs/importantLog.{#}.txt",
                "archiveNumbering": "Date",
                "archiveEvery": "Day",
                "archiveDateFormat": "yyyyMMdd",
                "layout": "${longdate}| ${uppercase:${level}}|  ${logger}|  ${message}   ${exception:format=tostring}"
            }
        },
        "rules": [
        {
        "levels": "Info, Warning, Error, Fatal",
        "logger": "*",
        "writeTo": "console"
        },
            {
                "logger": "*",
                "minLevel": "Trace",
                "writeTo": "allLogFile"
            },
            {
                "levels": "Debug, Error, Fatal",
                "logger": "*",
                "writeTo": "importantLogFile"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the AppSettings settings are in effect? It sounds like they are not and in a single-file publish, nlog.config is missing... just a suspicion.

Comment: @Fildor i put nlog configs into appsettings instead of nlog.config with this line of code:
` LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));` 
, and also looks like every other value i get in my application from appsettings works fine. Also in .csproj file I have these lines for appsettings to be created seperate from .exe
```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @Fjalee If using NLog.Extensions.Logging v5.0, then you only need this: `services.AddLogging(builder =>build.AddNLog());` without needing to explicitly create `NLogLoggingConfiguration`.

Comment: @Fjalee Consider enabling NLog Internal Loggger directly from code to troubleshoot what is happening: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging#example-with-internal-logging-from-code

Comment: @RolfKristensen So I tried internal logging you linked me, also I tried configuring NLog from code rather than from config file, still doesn't work. Also forgot to mention, logs that I log into console appear, so its not like logging doesn't work at all, it just doesn't create files while in single executable file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution after hours and hours of struggle.
so my allLog.txt file path was `"fileName": "${basedir}/logs/allLog.txt"`,
apparently if one file executable is created ${basedir} will become something into like `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\my_project_name\VnUDuP7f4QxGtrsSuaNaBXA_wxhYftr=\` , so to fix that I need to use `${basedir:fixtempdir=true}` instead of `${basedir}` so full path would be `${basedir:fixtempdir=true}/logs/allLog.txt`.

Comment: Excellent self research. The reason is that Microsoft failed to complete the illusion of the single-file-exe in NetCoreApp31. The single-file-exe is unzipped to a temp-directory, and this temp-dir becomes AppDomain.BaseDirectory See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3649 (Notice Microsoft fixes AppDomain.BaseDirectory with NET6, so you can remove the NLog-Hack when upgrading from NetCoreApp31)